# Showing $x^2 + y^2 + z^4 = 1$ is a Smooth surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show that $x^2 + y^2 + z^4 = 1$ is a Smooth surface, but i'm not sure how to show there exists a homeomorphism from an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $x^2+y^2+z^4=1$.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you know the regular value theorem?

Comment: @AlexS I'm not familiar with it, but I am guessing I need this to show there is a homeomorphism. This http://diffgeom.wiki-site.com/index.php/Regular_value_theorem ? I'm not entirely sure what that theorem is stating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to find a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^2$ and your surface because they are not the same topologically. What you will be able to find is a collection of homeomorphisms between open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ and open subsets of your set. For example, let $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2+z^4=1\}$$ be your set. Let $U_1=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2:a^2+b^2<1\}$ and $f_1(x,y)=(x,y,(1-x^2-y^2)^{1/4}).$ You need to show that $f_1$ is a (smooth) homeomorphism from $U$ (an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ to an open subset of $S$. But $f_1(U)$ doesn't cover all of $S$. You need to find other maps to cover the rest of $S$. I suggest $f_2=-f_1$, and using $U_2=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2:a^2+b^4<1\}$ as another open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ for the domain for the rest of your maps.

Comment: thank you so much for the well written answer. I understand now.